# Issue with paintComponent()

Tags: java, swing, paintcomponent, repaint

```
public class ImagePreview extends JPanel {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    final float ratio = 1.0f;
    private RenderedImage image;

    public ImagePreview (int imgWidth, int imgHeight) {

        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension((int) (ratio * imgWidth) + 5, (int) (ratio * imgHeight) + 5));
    }

    public ImagePreview (int imgWidth, int imgHeight, final RenderedImage image) {
        super();
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension((int) (ratio * imgWidth) + 5, (int) (ratio * imgHeight) + 5));
        this.image = image; 
        repaint();
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        VectorGraphics g2 = VectorGraphics.create(g);
        if (image != null) {
            g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
            g2.drawRenderedImage(image, AffineTransform.getScaleInstance(ratio, ratio));
        }
    }
}
```

this method is called on a button click
    // call this method 
    ImagePreview cart = new ImagePreview(imgWidth, imgHeight, image);

I am getting the image but it is not getting repaint on the Panel. I am unable in determine the reason behind that

Comment: You are using VectorGraphics which 3rd party framework is this? Or is this your code?

Comment: yes, this is my code and I am using import org.freehep.graphics2d.VectorGraphics; libary

Comment: You are passing RenderedImage to constructor, can you show how it is loaded?

Comment: ImagePreview cart = new ImagePreview (imgWidth, imgHeight, image);

Comment: @user3507196 I mean how `image` is created, RenderedImage is interface, what object is it and how its created?

Comment: public RenderedImage createMapImage() {
  // boundaries of the graph
  g2d.drawLine(xGridSize, yGridSize, xGridSize, imgHeight - yGridSize);
  g2d.drawLine(xGridSize, imgHeight - yGridSize, imgWidth - xGridSize, imgHeight - yGridSize); return bufferedImage;
 }

Comment: are you sure that the `image` is not null because in your code you have specified that if the `image` is null it will show nothing.

Comment: Yes, i have checked that by saving the same image into the disk. i am getting perfect image by expliciting saving it. But i just want to create a preview panel for the image and when ever i click a button image should be repaint

Comment: Does it help if you change `VectorGraphics g2 = VectorGraphics.create(g);` to `Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;` ?

Comment: No, i have tried both options but it is repaint on the panel

Comment: Is your ImagePreview set correctly on window? Try painting anything directly on it, a line or rectangel, and check if its visible.

Answer (score 1):

> But i just want to create a preview panel for the image

When you do custom painting you need to override the `getPreferredSize()` method of the panel to return the size of the image, otherwise the size is (0, 0) so there is nothing to paint.

```
VectorGraphics g2 = VectorGraphics.create(g);
```

Don't post code using 3rd party classes. We don't know if the problem is with your code or the class.

If you need more help post a proper [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem.